# Doing a linguistic sort in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sorting, unicode

In Oracle, in order to do a linguistic sort, suppose with arabic characters, I use following :

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_sort='arabic'
```

How can I achieve linguistic sorting in SQL Server 2008 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has the concept of [collations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726(v=sql.105).aspx) which affect ordering and comparison operations.

If your data is configured using a different collation to the one you require, you can force a specific one to sort by in your `ORDER BY` statement like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY TextColumn COLLATE Arabic_CI_AS
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidG. Between, If the datatype of my column is nvarchar, will it automatically sort it using its collation ?

Comment: Yes, by default, it will use the collation for that column.